# Reviews Date remove from magento

Tags: magento-1.9, review

HOW to remove reviews date in magento 
I tried this

```
.box-reviews dl dd small.date {
    display:none;
}
```

and also removed code

```
<small class="date"><?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?></small>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick for you..

```
.product-view .box-reviews dd small.date {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but not working

Comment: did you clear your cache?

Comment: yes i did but no effect

Comment: did you using the custom theme?

Comment: M using Easy Tabs extension  review tabs coming from there

Comment: No m using  TemplateMela theme

Comment: follow this you will find the file edit their http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment out that code from file. This is better solution than applying css.

```
  /app/design/frontend/{theme}/template/review/product/view/list.phtml
```

You can find below code in that file:

```
  <small class="date"><?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?></small>
```

Just comment it and clear cache and check it.

Comment: I have done this before but no effect

Comment: You need to enable admin path hint and check from where the file is coming for reviews. and remove code from that files. Thats it.!

Comment: For show path hint of files you can use this:  http://dragonfroot.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-for-frontend-admin-panel-in-magento/